# Anaconda 3 and Open CV3

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I would like to build Open CV3 from scratch with Anaconda 3 . I tried to find the instructions online but cannot find it. Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: Why you need to build instead of `conda install` OpenCV3 if you are using Anaconda 3?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume it is Linux, that you want to install opencv in /foo/opencv, that anaconda3 is installed in /foo/anaconda3. This should do it.

```
mkdir -p /foo/opencv/src
cd /foo/opencv/src
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip
unzip 3.2.0.zip
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/foo/opencv \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBuild_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -DBuild_opencv_python3=ON \
    -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/foo/anaconda3/bin/python \
    -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/foo/anaconda3/include/python3.6m \
    -DWITH_1394=OFF -DWITH_VTK=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_MATLAB=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    ../opencv-3.2.0
make
make install
```